# How do I make this check faster? (checking if the next item in array is higher than the next)

Tags: arrays, c

Theoretically this is correct, but its not fast enough. How do I make this faster?
This is in my opinion the only way to make this kind of check. I have to see if the next item in an array is higher than this one and if so make them the same height. If the second is smaller or equal to the first, nothing changes. I have to check how many days it takes to make sure all items are higher than the one after it. Each day, I have to check all items so if I have:
5 Elements:
41231
First day they become: 42331
Second day they become: 43331
All previous items are bigger or equal to the next so i print 2 days.

EDIT: Assert has to be used because i cannot modify that part of the program, as it reads the input and output from a file to see if its correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAXN 100000

int N, i, H[MAXN], giorni=-1, cambio=0;

int main() {
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    assert(1 == scanf("%d", &N));
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        assert(1 == scanf("%d", &H[i]));
    do{
        cambio=0;
        for(i=0; i<N; i++){
            if(H[i]<H[i+1]){
                H[i]=H[i+1];
                cambio++;
            }
        }
        giorni++;
    } while(cambio != 0);
    printf("%d\n", giorni);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not directly on point with your question, but it's a poor idea to use `assert()` with arguments having side effects because compiling with `NDEBUG` turns them all off.  For one-off test code it's probably OK, but be aware it's not a great practice.

Comment: You are misusing `assert()` — if you compile your program with `-DNDEBUG`, it fails to read any input.  You must be able to delete the `assert` lines without changing the behaviour of the program.

Comment: How about going backwards through the array? Then make `H[i] = H[i+1]` if `H[i] < H[i+1]`. This should solve the problem in one pass, if I understand it correclty

Comment: @ensc what do you mean? I don't understand

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm goes forward in the array, changing the current element. This may influence the previous elements, so you need multiple passes.

If you turn the algorithm around, by propagating bigger elements backwards, you only need one pass. Just ensure that the previous element is not less than the current:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAXN 100000

int N, i, H[MAXN], giorni=-1, cambio=0;

int main() {
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    assert(1 == scanf("%d", &N));
    for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
        int res = scanf("%d", &H[i]);
        assert(res == 1);
    }
    
    // Changed core loop
    for(i=N-2; i>=0; --i){
        if(H[i]<H[i+1]){
            H[i]=H[i+1];
        }
    }
    
    // This will now always be 0
    giorni++;
    printf("%d\n", giorni);
    return 0;
}
```

NB: I also fixed the assert problem